# How can I pass a variable from Node.js Express to an EJS HTML file for toggling alert displays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, ejs

Hey so basically I am trying to send a variable from my app.js file to my ejs html file so that I can toggle when an alert is displayed.

This is what my app.js for this part of code looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Wki.png)

This is what my first attempt was:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVJwv.png)
I tried putting all sorts of brackets like <%= %>, <= =>, {{ }}, ect.(all with and w/o quotation marks) around searcherror when I am defining the variable in the ejs file but none of them worked.

After doing a fair amount of research, I came to the conclusion that I am unable to access my ejs variables inside of script tags in html for whatever reasons.

To combat this, I created this work around which I believe should work, but for whatever reason it does not. Note: the div does show up with the correct text value if I turn off hidden.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVLMv.png)

Stuff at top of app.js file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrWE0.png)

Any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

When you post code, it's helpful to post the actual text rather than images, so folks can copy and paste.

As an example, this worked for me:

Express route:

```
router.get("/supersecretroute", (req, res, next) => {
  const someVar = { person: { name: "Tristan", display: false } };
  res.render("pages/index", { someVar });
});
```

index.ejs:

```
    <main>
        <section id="some-section">
            <h2>Variable</h2>
            <p display="<%= someVar.person.display %>">
                <%= someVar.person.name %>
            </p>
        </section>
    </main>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! Sorry about the code, I will make sure to copy and paste going forward! So your solution does work, but the problem I have isn't that the variable isn't displaying, its that I am unable to access the variable within my javascript functions.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Try adding the JS inside of a DOMContentLoaded event listener, e.g. 
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        const toDisplay = document.querySelector('p').textContent
        console.log(toDisplay);
    }, false);`